# Using MVC4, need to pass input to stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 and retrieve the result and display it in view

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to the MVC concepts, I need to learn it quickly before my new project begins in a couple of weeks. I just want to know one thing, how to pass an input to a SQL Server 2012 stored procedure using Entity Framework and retrieve the results and display it in view using ASP.NET MVC 4.

If some one help me to do this it would be grateful, I can move on learning this basic steps.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't so simple and better to answer it with links to articles:

1. [Work with Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 3/4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4)
2. [Stored procedures in the Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx)